# PHP Composer does not report reason for choosing to skip a version of a package. Why / How to change?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a custom platform that I deploy to projects via composer. My new version is version `v3.6.29`. It turns out that one of my new dependencies for this project got a random `$` character inserted into the middle  of the package name (due to my fat fingers) in the `composer.json` file of the platform, which basically broke it.

I went to the site I wanted to install this new version for and did `composer update vendor/pkg-name` and it goes through and checks and just says its has nothing to update... but I know for a fact there is an update. So obviously there is some reason it chose not to install the new version...

But why?

You would think composer would be smart enough to think that I might want to know the reason it chose not to update to to the latest compatible version, right? I guess not! But how can I force this in the future?

I tried `composer update -vvv vendor/pkg-name` and that literally told me nothing new.

I also tried `composer why-not` and `composer prohibits` for my package and received no useful information.

The only way I was able to find out what the problem was, was by doing:

```
rm -rf vendor;
rm -rf composer.lock;
vim composer.json
-- Change version of my platform from "~3.6.0" to the specific version I wanted to install, "3.6.29"
-- Save / Quit Vim
composer install
```

And then I finally get this output:

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires vendor/pkg-name 3.6.29 -> satisfiable by vendor/pkg-name[v3.6.29].
    - vendor/pkg-name v3.6.29 requires vendor2/pkg$name2 ^2.8 -> could not be found, it looks like its name is invalid, "$" is not allowed in package names.
```

I mean do you think, maybe, quite possibly, that I might want to know this is the reason that it would not upgrade to the latest version? Maybe not, I guess in a normal scenario the installer might not care about the reason but from my point of view, as the developer of said package that is refusing to install to the latest, I want to know why its skipping it.

My questions is simply this:
When composer refuses to install the version of a package you want, and that you know exists, but is not telling you WHY, how can you FORCE it to explain it's self when it decides to fall back to a version that is "acceptable" to it rather than the optimal version?

I feel like jumping through the hoops I had to jump through to figure out the problem cannot possibly be the best way to accomplish this? What am I missing here?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say you "tried composer why-not and composer prohibits for my package and received no useful information", did you receive *any* output?

Comment: Was a while ago, so I dont remember what it said but it definitely didnt mention anything about a problem with the version I wanted to update to. Maybe I needed to do `composer why-not vendor/pkg-name:3.6.29` as I'm not 100% sure I passed a version number to the command line... in which case that would be the "answer" to my question that is over a month old and literally no one was been able to answer :shrug:

Comment: Well, people were probably waiting for you to respond to my request for clarification. I guess you can learn two things here: firstly, including the details of what you've tried and what happened is more useful than lots of words describing how you feel about it; and secondly, next time, don't leave it a month before checking for responses.

Comment: I got busy, & this is tied to my gmail where it was lost in the junk mail, my bad. Once I fixed it I moved on and forgot I posted this until I came back the other day for something and noticed the notification icon. Again, my bad. Honestly I could do with out being talked down. Sure I was pretty annoyed and stressed out when I made the post and it showed through but I'm capable of learning my own lessons without your help. I wasn't trying to be an ass with my last comment, so I'm sorry if it came off that way. It just seemed to me that no one knew the answer since no one else tried to answer.